# Error inflating class <unknown> in 2 activities that used to work

Tags: android, class, android-inflate

hi im having a problem in 2 activities in my app that is throwing this error, Error inflating class 
it seems to be similar to this question ; [Unknown inflate error with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847478/unknown-inflate-error-with-android)

one of the activities is doing nothing but loading an animation and used to work fine i don't believe i have changed anything and it has no XML errors i'm getting this in the log

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating
```

class 
can anyone see what i have done wrong? i'm still quite new at this, here is my code

xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layered"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bus_image"
    android:id="@+id/busImageView"
    android:background="@drawable/movingbus"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bus_text"
    android:id="@+id/text_View"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/fnshdbtn"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="nextImage2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_View"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nextbutton" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

java

```
public class BusActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
AnimationDrawable schoolBus;
Button b;
Button btn;
TextView t;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_View);
    Typeface newfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MarkerFelt.ttf");
    t.setTypeface(newfont);
    ImageView movingbus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.busImageView);
    movingbus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.movingbus);
    schoolBus = (AnimationDrawable) movingbus.getBackground();

    schoolBus.start();




    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(BusActivity.this, R.raw.bushorn);
            mp.start();
        }
    });



}

public void nextImage2(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, socialActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

and here is the log cat

```
--- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
04-26 01:34:36.021    6000-6000/com.martinsapp.socialstories D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting 

down VM
04-26 01:34:36.021    6000-6000/com.martinsapp.socialstories W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1:   
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d76d88)
04-26 01:34:36.031    6000-6000/com.martinsapp.socialstories E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL    
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.martinsapp.socialstories, PID: 6000
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    
ComponentInfo{com.martinsapp.socialstories/com.martinsapp.socialstories.BusActivity}:  
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at     
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating  

class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)

at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutIn
flater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at   
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at   
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.
superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:208)
        at  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.
setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
        at  
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
        at com.martinsapp.socialstories.BusActivity.onCreate(BusActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

(ActivityThread.java:2212)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)   
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
```

Comment: I think this is not related to the thread you posted, but rather to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class?rq=1

Comment: issue could be with the images your using. try to change the images

Comment: Did you try to clean the project?

Comment: @Libin could the images be the issue even if they used to load just fine?

Comment: @Henry how do u clean projects in android studio?

Comment: Yes possible, on random scenario. Since your log shows " allocation failed for scaled bitmap"

Comment: @Libin how can I mark your answer as correct? Thank you very much

Comment: I have added my comments as an Answer, now you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your log `allocation failed for scaled bitmap`.

Issue could be with the images your using. Try to change the image.

This crash might be happening due to `out of memory` in random scenario.